# Apache crashed under the yaf framework when loading xdebug.

Tags: php, xdebug

so my php.ini was this :

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\xampp\tmp"

[yaf]
extension=php_yaf-2.2.7-x86-5.4.x-zts-nodebug.dll
;extension=php_yaf.dll
yaf.action_prefer=on
extension=php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9.dll
extension=php_igbinary.dll
extension=php_redis.dll
```

and I download yaf_sample_1.1.0 Featured from
http://code.google.com/p/yafphp/downloads/list

so I visit URL:

```
http://localhost/sample/index.php
```

When my breakpoint step into index.php line 21( ->run(); )  Apache  crashed,  why ?

index.php

```
$response = $application
    ->bootstrap()/*bootstrap是可选的调用*/
    ->run()/*执行*/;     //this place   apache crached ...
```

Is there anyone can help me?  thanks!

Comment: i was using  xampp environment！